# Is it possible to add fields to a Form's mapping after its initial definition?

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

Say I have a little form, for example:

```
val myForm = Form(
  mapping(
    "street" -> nonEmptyText,
    "streetNumber" -> nonEmptyText
  )(myApply)(myUnapply)
)
```

Is there a way to add fields to myForm's mapping at a later point? (i.e Adding an `"apartmentFloor" -> text` mapping, or a `"houseName" -> text` according to some criteria)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As detailed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13714673/how-can-i-apply-a-play-2-uniqueness-validation-only-when-an-object-is-being-crea/14306301#14306301), mappings can be defined separately and combined in your various forms.

You can also build a form on the fly, like this:

```
def passwordResetRequest() = Action {
   Form("email" -> email).bindFromRequest(...,...)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't seem to be possible.

The framework defines the [`Mapping`-Trait](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/api/2.0/scala/play/api/data/Mapping.html), which does not seem to allow modification (i.e. it's immutable). You could probably implement your own Mapping which allows modification at a later time, but I'd assume that the Play developers had something in mind when they designed the trait like this.